# Binding data to a control within user control in VB 2013

Tags: vb.net, combobox, user-controls

I have designed a user control in Visual Studio 2013 (VB) . The control contains three Combobox controls through which user can select different values. I bind each combobox to a specific table field in my database (SQL Server) through assigning each combobox's properties [DataSourse, DisplayMember, and ValueMember] the required values. I already created a DataSet.

When I add multiple instances  (about 26) of my user-control to a form and run the application, the comboboxes SHOW nothing! as if they are empty. To make sure, I added a Combobox control on the form itself (where user-control instances added), and bind it the same way above, and .. mmm it works!

I'm not able to explain the reason behind this strange behaviour.

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Does it work when you only have one of your user controls?